# Makefile doesn't run command correctly

Tags: makefile, sh

When I execute the following command in `sh`, it works as expected:

```
    sed -i "s/^\\(const SIZE int = \\).*\$/\\1`du -bs myfile.exe | sed 's/[[:blank:]].*//'`"/g myfile.go
```

But when I run it in a Makefile, I get this:

```
sed -i "s/^\\(const SIZE int = \\).*\\\1`du -bs myfile.exe | sed 's/[[:blank:]].*//'`"/g myfile.go
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unterminated `s' command
```

It looks like make is changing what the command is in the Makefile. How ideas on how to get make to run the command correctly?

Comment: That's a pretty involved command, using double quotes, single quotes *and* backtics. Could you tell us what it's supposed to do. maybe show us the "before" and "after" lines?

Comment: ...And are you sure that final `/g` should be *outside* the double quotes?

Comment: @Beta The `/g` is still part of the *word* that is partially defined by the quoted string. Quotes don't define a string in shell, they just bulk-escape their contents. `"foo"/g` is equivalent to `\f\o\o/g`.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/1154203/506107): Apparently make *does* need some things to be escaped. The `$` after the `const SIZE int = \\).*\` needs to be escaped for make to not want to do its own variable substitution.

Escaping it with `\$$` worked.